# How to write list in a new Mode (abap)

Tags: abap

```
  LOOP AT gt_file INTO ls_file.
    WRITE:/ ls_file.
  ENDLOOP.
```

This is the output of my list. When a user hits a Button (Function 'On_user_command') this list should be shown in a new window/mode.

Is there any function or command to solve this?

Comment: new window/mode or simple popup? Modal or amodal? What is exactly the need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the transaction of the list and create a new mode.

```
 CALL FUNCTION 'ABAP4_CALL_TRANSACTION'
        STARTING NEW TASK 'NewTask'
        DESTINATION 'NONE'
  EXPORTING
    tcode = 'ZLIST'
*    skip_screen = 'X'
*    mode_val = 'E'
*    update_val = 'A'
*  TABLES
*    using_tab = bdcdata_tab
  EXCEPTIONS
    call_transaction_denied = 1
    OTHERS = 2.
```

Comment: Generally speaking, any RFC-enabled function module which displays a screen can be used (i.e. ABAP4_CALL_TRANSACTION & transaction code are not specifically required).